# Fitting complex equation

Tags: fitting, convolution

I used the following code for fitting but it does not produce an output.I kept it nearly 3 to 4 hours but it does not give any output. How should I make it correct?I have used two equation(f1,f2).I want to convolute f2 with Voight function and then add f1 with that and find the parameters. This is my data.

```
Data-[{0.720093, 0.295084}, {0.717593, 0.294154}, {0.71511, 
  0.293408}, {0.712644, 0.292561}, {0.710195, 0.291841}, {0.707763, 
  0.290859}, {0.705347, 0.289796}, {0.702948, 0.288597}, {0.700565, 
  0.287483}, {0.698198, 0.286434}, {0.695847, 0.285242}, {0.693512, 
  0.28415}, {0.691193, 0.283081}, {0.688889, 0.281928}, {0.6866, 
  0.28078}, {0.684327, 0.279592}, {0.682068, 0.278541}, {0.679825, 
  0.277436}, {0.677596, 0.27651}, {0.675381, 0.275654}, {0.673181, 
  0.274795}, {0.670996, 0.273949}, {0.668824, 0.272901}, {0.666667, 
  0.271992}, {0.664523, 0.271335}, {0.662393, 0.270664}, {0.660277, 
  0.269989}, {0.658174, 0.26921}, {0.656085, 0.268645}, {0.654008, 
  0.26808}, {0.651945, 0.267374}, {0.649895, 0.266843}, {0.647858, 
  0.266955}, {0.645833, 0.267217}, {0.643821, 0.267661}, {0.641822, 
  0.267598}, {0.639835, 0.267401}, {0.63786, 0.267703}, {0.635897, 
  0.268113}, {0.633947, 0.269681}, {0.632008, 0.27114}, {0.630081, 
  0.272627}, {0.628166, 0.274489}, {0.626263, 0.276107}, {0.624371, 
  0.277585}, {0.62249, 0.278766}, {0.620621, 0.280244}, {0.618762, 
  0.281839}, {0.616915, 0.283631}, {0.615079, 0.284915}, {0.613254, 
  0.285762}, {0.61144, 0.286192}, {0.609636, 0.288746}, {0.607843, 
  0.29093}, {0.606061, 0.292403}, {0.604288, 0.293922}, {0.602527, 
  0.297144}, {0.600775, 0.299701}, {0.599034, 0.302432}, {0.597303, 
  0.304511}, {0.595581, 0.309842}, {0.59387, 0.313888}, {0.592168, 
  0.318189}, {0.590476, 0.319657}, {0.588794, 0.320562}, {0.587121, 
  0.321366}, {0.585458, 0.321272}, {0.583804, 0.31859}, {0.58216, 
  0.315947}, {0.580524, 0.313623}, {0.578898, 0.310534}, {0.577281, 
  0.304952}, {0.575673, 0.298553}, {0.574074, 0.290369}, {0.572484, 
  0.279767}, {0.570902, 0.26778}, {0.56933, 0.2571}, {0.567766, 
  0.244668}, {0.56621, 0.22961}, {0.564663, 0.215466}, {0.563124, 
  0.200814}, {0.561594, 0.184229}, {0.560072, 0.169114}, {0.558559, 
  0.153148}, {0.557053, 0.137587}, {0.555556, 0.122651}, {0.548187, 
  0.108596}, {0.546737, 0.092986}, {0.545295, 0.0785259}, {0.54386, 
  0.0709461}, {0.542432, 0.0609015}, {0.541012, 0.0524228}, {0.5396, 
  0.0465767}, {0.538194, 0.0402518}, {0.536797, 0.0339568}, {0.535406,
   0.0290519}, {0.534022, 0.0210021}, {0.532646, 
  0.0163296}, {0.531277, 0.0125908}, {0.529915, 0.011545}, {0.528559, 
  0.00787535}, {0.527211, 0.00539227}, {0.525869, 
  0.00218363}, {0.524535, -4.67229*10^-6}}]


    data = Import["E:\\FITTING DATA\\Sheet1.txt", "Table"]; 
        original = 
         ListLinePlot[data, AxesLabel -> {count, intensity}, 
          PlotStyle -> {Red}, Frame -> True]
        f1 = a*UnitStep[x - b]*c*
          Sqrt[x - b]*(Pi*Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[x - b]*Exp[Pi*Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[x - b]])/
           Sinh[Pi*Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[x - b]]
        f2 = a*d*Sum[(4*Pi)/n^3*DiracDelta[x - b + d/n^2], {n, 1, 1}]
        f3 = Convolve[
          a*d*Sum[(4*Pi)/n^3*DiracDelta[x - b + d/n^2], {n, 1, 1}], 
          Re[Erfc[(\[Delta] + I*x)/(Sqrt[2]*\[Sigma])]/
            E^((x - I*\[Delta])^2/(2*\[Sigma]^2))], x, y]
        fit2 = NonlinearModelFit[
           data, {a*UnitStep[y - b]*c*
              Sqrt[y - 
                b]*(Pi*Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[y - b]*Exp[Pi*Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[y - b]])/
               Sinh[Pi*Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[y - b]] + 

             Convolve[
              a*d*Sum[(4*Pi)/n^3*DiracDelta[x - b + d/n^2], {n, 1, 1}], 
              Re[Erfc[(\[Delta] + I*x)/(Sqrt[2]*\[Sigma])]/
                E^((x - I*\[Delta])^2/(2*\[Sigma]^2))], x, y], 
            b < Min[data[[All, 1]]], 
                 Inequality[10, Less, a, Greater, 15], 0.01 < c < 0.1, 
            Inequality[0.001, Less, d, Greater, 0.01]}, {{a, 10}, {b, -1}, c, 
            d, \[Delta], \[Sigma]}, y]; 
        fit2["BestFitParameters"]
        Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
          AxesLabel -> {count, intensity}], 
         Plot[fit2[y], {y, 1.3, 0.55}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}], Frame -> True]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Inequality[10, Less, a, Greater, 15]` is `10 < a && a > 15`

`Inequality[0.001, Less, d, Greater, 0.01]` is `0.001 < d && d > 0.01`

I doubt that is what you meant. I'm guessing you meant `10<a<15` and `0.001<d<0.01`

Note: Thank you for your raw data. It would have been impossible to do this without that.

This

```
data =
{{0.720093, 0.295084}, {0.717593, 0.294154}, {0.71511, 0.293408}, {0.712644, 0.292561},
 {0.710195, 0.291841}, {0.707763, 0.290859}, {0.705347, 0.289796}, {0.702948, 0.288597},
 {0.700565, 0.287483}, {0.698198, 0.286434}, {0.695847, 0.285242}, {0.693512, 0.28415},
 {0.691193, 0.283081}, {0.688889, 0.281928}, {0.6866, 0.28078}, {0.684327, 0.279592},
 {0.682068, 0.278541}, {0.679825, 0.277436}, {0.677596, 0.27651}, {0.675381, 0.275654},
 {0.673181, 0.274795}, {0.670996, 0.273949}, {0.668824, 0.272901}, {0.666667, 0.271992},
 {0.664523, 0.271335}, {0.662393, 0.270664}, {0.660277, 0.269989}, {0.658174, 0.26921},
 {0.656085, 0.268645}, {0.654008, 0.26808}, {0.651945, 0.267374}, {0.649895, 0.266843},
 {0.647858, 0.266955}, {0.645833, 0.267217}, {0.643821, 0.267661}, {0.641822, 0.267598},
 {0.639835, 0.267401}, {0.63786, 0.267703}, {0.635897, 0.268113},  {0.633947, 0.269681},
 {0.632008, 0.27114}, {0.630081, 0.272627}, {0.628166, 0.274489}, {0.626263, 0.276107},
 {0.624371, 0.277585}, {0.62249, 0.278766}, {0.620621, 0.280244}, {0.618762, 0.281839},
 {0.616915, 0.283631}, {0.615079, 0.284915}, {0.613254, 0.285762}, {0.61144, 0.286192},
 {0.609636, 0.288746}, {0.607843, 0.29093}, {0.606061, 0.292403}, {0.604288, 0.293922},
 {0.602527, 0.297144}, {0.600775, 0.299701}, {0.599034, 0.302432}, {0.597303, 0.304511},
 {0.595581, 0.309842}, {0.59387, 0.313888}, {0.592168, 0.318189}, {0.590476, 0.319657},
 {0.588794, 0.320562}, {0.587121, 0.321366}, {0.585458, 0.321272}, {0.583804, 0.31859},
 {0.58216, 0.315947}, {0.580524, 0.313623}, {0.578898, 0.310534}, {0.577281, 0.304952},
 {0.575673, 0.298553}, {0.574074, 0.290369}, {0.572484, 0.279767}, {0.570902, 0.26778},
 {0.56933, 0.2571}, {0.567766, 0.244668}, {0.56621, 0.22961}, {0.564663, 0.215466},
 {0.563124, 0.200814}, {0.561594, 0.184229}, {0.560072, 0.169114}, {0.558559, 0.153148},
 {0.557053, 0.137587}, {0.555556, 0.122651}, {0.548187, 0.108596}, {0.546737, 0.092986},
 {0.545295, 0.0785259}, {0.54386, 0.0709461}, {0.542432, 0.0609015}, {0.541012, 0.0524228},
 {0.5396, 0.0465767}, {0.538194, 0.0402518}, {0.536797, 0.0339568}, {0.535406, 0.0290519},
 {0.534022, 0.0210021}, {0.532646, 0.0163296}, {0.531277, 0.0125908}, {0.529915, 0.011545},
 {0.528559, 0.00787535}, {0.527211, 0.00539227}, {0.525869, 0.00218363}, {0.524535, -4.67229*10^-6}};
(*data=Import["E:\\FITTING DATA\\Sheet1.txt","Table"];*)
Print[original = ListLinePlot[data, AxesLabel -> {count, intensity}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red}, Frame -> True]];
f1 = a*UnitStep[y - b]*c*Sqrt[y - b]*(Pi*Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[y - b]*
  Exp[Pi*Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[y - b]])/Sinh[Pi*Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[y - b]];
f2 = a*d*Sum[(4*Pi)/n^3*DiracDelta[x - b + d/n^2], {n, 1, 1}];
f3 = Convolve[f2, Re[Erfc[(δ + I*x)/(Sqrt[2]*σ)]/E^((x - I*δ)^2/(2*σ^2))], x, y];
system = {f1+f3, b<Min[data[[All, 1]]], 10<a<15, 0.01<c<0.1, 0.001<d<0.01};
fit2 = NonlinearModelFit[data, system, {{a, 10}, {b, -1}, c, d, δ, σ}, y];
Print[fit2["BestFitParameters"]];
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red}, AxesLabel -> {count, intensity}],
  Plot[fit2[y], {y, 1.3, 0.55}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

finishes in about 20 seconds.

I am guessing you need to adjust your model or perhaps set some initial parameters to get a better fit to your data.

I believe the reason this is slow is almost exactly the same reason your previous question was slow. I sped this one up using exactly the same technique as used with your previous question.

Please check all this very very carefully to try to make certain that I have not made any mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible for me to get good fitting by changing the 
 initial parameters?

Comment: That is a more difficult question to answer. I can't tell whether you are only trying to fit a portion of the data. I can't tell whether you have selected an appropriate model for that data. I don't know what you are really trying to accomplish. Because of all of that I haven't even looked at whether I could change what you are trying to do.

Comment: How do I apply range for my parameters?